# Attribute should not be changed after creation

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, encapsulation

Given the question - "All game objects provide the ability for external code to obtain their size. However, they do not provide the ability to have their size changed once it is created."

If I have a parent class with private fields such as this `GameObject` class:

```
public abstract class GameObject {
     private int size;

     public void setSize(int size) {
          this.size = size;
     }
}
```

and a children classes such as

```
public class Dinosaur extends GameObject {
     public Dinosaur() {
           this.setSize(100);
     }
}

public class Jeep extends GameObject {
     public Jeep() {
          this.setSize(10);
     }
 }
```

How do I ensure that the size is not changed after the object is created?
I am confused because if I make the setter method for size private then I cannot set the size for each `GameObject` individually upon creation.

EDIT: Added second child class for clarity.

Comment: It would be good if you also use the parent class or why did you create it?

Comment: @AKSW I'm sorry what do you mean by use the parent class?

Comment: I just referred to your text. You said that you "have a parent class with private fields ... " What's unclear here? And I only wanted to say that you never used that class when defining children classes which would basically the main use-case of abstract classes in Java ...

Comment: ok, now you changed your code ... would be good if you document those updates because all answers here relied on your old code and now every answer/comment looks strange to people reading it

Comment: Should I be adding edit notes within the text when I update the question? I've been using the built in edit notes.

Comment: And to be honest, I do not understand your problem. You have an abstract parent class, thus, subclasses inherit this method. If you restrict the scope, indeed as instances are always of the child type, the method can't be called again. I don't see any solution that avoids this and for good reasons it's not the case.

Comment: Would be good next time, you know otherwise it's getting a bit confusing with older answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to make the `size` variable unchangeable then you should use final modifier.
There are 2 ways to set the value for this kind of variables: 1) constructor 2) inline. As long as you would like to have an option to set your custom value in the client code for each object, you should use constructor:

```
public abstract class GameObject {

     private final int size;

     public GameObject(int size) {
         this.size = size;
     }
}

public Dinosaur extends GameObject {

   pubilc Dinosaur(int size){
       super(size);
   }
}
```

There is no need in setter method in that case.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments of the other answers, the issue is that there could be other `GameObject` subclasses that will want to modify `size`.

Comment: This is a reasonable remark, thanks. Nevertheless, we have a condition: "All **game objects** provide the ability for external code to obtain their size. However, they **do not provide the ability to have their size changed** once it is created."

Comment: @VasiliyVlasov Thank you, I was stuck thinking that the only way to set the attribute was through a method call. This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

`size` can be `final` and size value passed in the constructor. Also you do not need a setter. You can make only the necessary getter.

```
public abstract class GameObject {
    private final int size;

    public GameObject(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

     public int getSize() {
         return this.size;
     }
}
```

Comment: Problem is there could be other subclasses that want to change `size`.

Comment: @arshajii Only subclasses can change the size?

Answer (score 1):

They're a few things wrong with your code.

First if the class shouldn't have the ability to set the size after creation, why provide a setter in the first place?

Second, a subclass could override your setSize `method` in the `abstract` class and do whatever it wanted. If you want `inheritance` do this:

```
public abstract class GameObject {

    private final size;

    public GameObject(int size){
        this.size = size;
    }
}

public class Dinosaur extends GameObject {

    public Dinosaur(int size){
        super(size)
    }
}
```

No setter is provided and the size must be made available at construction time. If you want a method to do it, make the method `final`. Like this:

```
public final setSize(int size){
   this.size = size;
}
```

By making it `final` the subclasses have to except the method as it is, no overriding.

Another approach is, make this class [immutable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html). You don't use `setters`, but you can have `getters`, and the class would be made `final`, so no subclassing.

```
public final Dinosaur {

   private final int size;

   pubilc Dinosaur(int size){
       this.size = size;
   }

   public int getSize(){
       return this.size;
   }
}
```

Comment: Problem is that there could be other subclasses that will want to change `size`.

Comment: I think the OP is missing an `extends GameObject` on `Dinosaur`.

Comment: But `size` is a field of `GameObject`; you're shadowing it in your `Dinosaur` class.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: I'm assuming you meant to have `Dinosaur` extend `GameObject`.)

You could override the `setSize()` method and throw an exception:

```
public class Dinosaur extends GameObject {
    ...

    @Override
    public void setSize(int size) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("can't change dinosaur size");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Given the question - "All game objects provide the ability for
>   external code to obtain their size. However, they do not provide the
>   ability to have their size changed once it is created."

The usual way that this is done is by having the constructor of the parent class accept a size argument.  This argument sets the value of an immutable size field.  Subclasses may easily access this value, but they are unable to change it once it has been set.  This is the most object-oriented way in which to meet the listed requirements.

For example:

```
public abstract class GameObject {
    private final int size;

    public GameObject(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int size() { return this.size; }
    :
    :
}
```

and a child class:

```
public class Dinosaur extends GameObject {

    public Dinosaur() {
        super(100);
    }
    :
    :
}
```

Although there is some discussion in this thread about how subclasses may dynamically change the size field, a better design would be to use an immutable design like the one presented here and have client code request a new object with a different size if needed (say, with a `copyOf()` method).  Immutable designs have several advantages over mutable ones and are usually the way to go when planning value classes.